# material-table checkbox did not get selected when using useState (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, material-table

Hi there I am new in react, I am having problem in material-table which is the checkboxes do not get selected when useState is used alongside onSelectionChange. I have created a table and set a onSelectedChange() function and inside I add useState() with data taken from the onSelectionChange. The checkbox does not get checked when I click. Please help me.

code:

```
  const [selects, setSelects] = useState({});
  const handleCheckboxClick = (rowData) => {
    setSelects({
      selectedItems: {
        ...rowData,
        tableData: {
          checked: true,
        },
      },
    });
  };

 <MaterialTable
        title="Asset Group"
        options={[
    pageSizeOptions: false,
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
        },
        selection: true,
     showFirstLastPageButtons: false,
    ]}
        columns={assetGroupColumns}
        onSelectionChange={(event) => {
          handleCheckboxClick(event);
    //console.log(event)
        }}
        data={arrangeData(data.asset_group)}
        components={{
          Toolbar: (props) => (
            <div style={{ display: "none" }}>
              <MTableToolbar {...props} />
            </div>
          ),
        }}
      />
    </>
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hi please take this example below. This is very large example but it works perfectly for your requirement.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import {lighten, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import FilterListIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';

function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
    return {name, calories, fat, carbs, protein};
}

const rows = [
    createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
    createData('Donut', 452, 25.0, 51, 4.9),
    createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
    createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
    createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
    createData('Honeycomb', 408, 3.2, 87, 6.5),
    createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
    createData('Jelly Bean', 375, 0.0, 94, 0.0),
    createData('KitKat', 518, 26.0, 65, 7.0),
    createData('Lollipop', 392, 0.2, 98, 0.0),
    createData('Marshmallow', 318, 0, 81, 2.0),
    createData('Nougat', 360, 19.0, 9, 37.0),
    createData('Oreo', 437, 18.0, 63, 4.0),
];

function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
    if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
    return order === 'desc'
        ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
        : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}

function stableSort(array, comparator) {
    const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
    stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
        const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
        if (order !== 0) return order;
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });
    return stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);
}

const headCells = [
    {id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Dessert (100g serving)'},
    {id: 'calories', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Calories'},
    {id: 'fat', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Fat (g)'},
    {id: 'carbs', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Carbs (g)'},
    {id: 'protein', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Protein (g)'},
];

function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
    const {classes, onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort} = props;
    const createSortHandler = (property) => (event) => {
        onRequestSort(event, property);
    };

    return (
        <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    <Checkbox
                        indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
                        checked={rowCount > 0 && numSelected === rowCount}
                        onChange={onSelectAllClick}
                        inputProps={{'aria-label': 'select all desserts'}}
                    />
                </TableCell>
                {headCells.map((headCell) => (
                    <TableCell
                        key={headCell.id}
                        align={headCell.numeric ? 'right' : 'left'}
                        padding={headCell.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'default'}
                        sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                    >
                        <TableSortLabel
                            active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                            direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : 'asc'}
                            onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                        >
                            {headCell.label}
                            {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                                <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                  {order === 'desc' ? 'sorted descending' : 'sorted ascending'}
                </span>
                            ) : null}
                        </TableSortLabel>
                    </TableCell>
                ))}
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
    );
}

EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    order: PropTypes.oneOf(['asc', 'desc']).isRequired,
    orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

const useToolbarStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        paddingLeft: theme.spacing(2),
        paddingRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    highlight:
        theme.palette.type === 'light'
            ? {
                color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
                backgroundColor: lighten(theme.palette.secondary.light, 0.85),
            }
            : {
                color: theme.palette.text.primary,
                backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.dark,
            },
    title: {
        flex: '1 1 100%',
    },
}));

const EnhancedTableToolbar = (props) => {
    const classes = useToolbarStyles();
    const {numSelected} = props;

    return (
        <Toolbar
            className={clsx(classes.root, {
                [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
            })}
        >
            {numSelected > 0 ? (
                <Typography className={classes.title} color="inherit" variant="subtitle1" component="div">
                    {numSelected} selected
                </Typography>
            ) : (
                <Typography className={classes.title} variant="h6" id="tableTitle" component="div">
                    Nutrition
                </Typography>
            )}

            {numSelected > 0 ? (
                <Tooltip title="Delete">
                    <IconButton aria-label="delete">
                        <DeleteIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            ) : (
                <Tooltip title="Filter list">
                    <IconButton aria-label="filter list">
                        <FilterListIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
            )}
        </Toolbar>
    );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
    numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    paper: {
        width: '100%',
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    table: {
        minWidth: 750,
    },
    visuallyHidden: {
        border: 0,
        clip: 'rect(0 0 0 0)',
        height: 1,
        margin: -1,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        padding: 0,
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 20,
        width: 1,
    },
}));

export default function EnhancedTable() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState('calories');
    const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [dense, setDense] = React.useState(false);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === 'asc';
        setOrder(isAsc ? 'desc' : 'asc');
        setOrderBy(property);
    };

    const handleSelectAllClick = (event) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            const newSelecteds = rows.map((n) => n.name);
            setSelected(newSelecteds);
            return;
        }
        setSelected([]);
    };

    const handleClick = (event, name) => {
        const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(name);
        let newSelected = [];

        if (selectedIndex === -1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, name);
        } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
        } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
        } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
            newSelected = newSelected.concat(
                selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
                selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
            );
        }

        setSelected(newSelected);
    };

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

    const handleChangeDense = (event) => {
        setDense(event.target.checked);
    };

    const isSelected = (name) => selected.indexOf(name) !== -1;

    const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length}/>
                <TableContainer>
                    <Table
                        className={classes.table}
                        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                        size={dense ? 'small' : 'medium'}
                        aria-label="enhanced table"
                    >
                        <EnhancedTableHead
                            classes={classes}
                            numSelected={selected.length}
                            order={order}
                            orderBy={orderBy}
                            onSelectAllClick={handleSelectAllClick}
                            onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                            rowCount={rows.length}
                        />
                        <TableBody>
                            {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                .map((row, index) => {
                                    const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.name);
                                    const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                                    return (
                                        <TableRow
                                            hover
                                            onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row.name)}
                                            role="checkbox"
                                            aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                            tabIndex={-1}
                                            key={row.name}
                                            selected={isItemSelected}
                                        >
                                            <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                                                <Checkbox
                                                    checked={isItemSelected}
                                                    inputProps={{'aria-labelledby': labelId}}
                                                />
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" padding="none">
                                                {row.name}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    );
                                })}
                            {emptyRows > 0 && (
                                <TableRow style={{height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows}}>
                                    <TableCell colSpan={6}/>
                                </TableRow>
                            )}
                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
                <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                    component="div"
                    count={rows.length}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
            </Paper>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={<Switch checked={dense} onChange={handleChangeDense}/>}
                label="Dense padding"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Source](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with the following:

```
const handleCheckboxClick = (rowData) => {
    rowData.tableData.checked = true
};
```

and you can call it with the following:

```
onSelectionChange={(evt, rowData: any) => {
    handleCheckboxClick(rowData);
}}
```